# Need help to get a server to login to SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server, connectivity, logins

I created a virtual machine (VM) on Azure to host Sparx Enterprise Architect cloud-based repositories using Pro Cloud Server (PCS)
https://sparxsystems.com/products/procloudserver/30-min-tour/index.html

I installed PCS, then installed Installed SQL Server Express on the same VM, created a database, tested it with a simple SELECT statement and it's working.
In Pro Cloud Config Client, I tried to connect to the database but I could not. I am getting login error message (screenshot below).

[image]
On the VM, I created a port rule for 1433 (screenshot below).

[image]

The server name, the DB name, the username and password are all correct (screenshot below). I am not sure why I am still unable to connect to the DB?

[image]
I would greatly appreciate your insights.

Comment: It's not about "server was not found", it says you LOGIN FAILED, you should check SQL server errorlog (`exec xp_readerrorlog` from SSMS) and you'll see there the reason (password did not match, login not found, database is not online, ecc) in the last rows of the resultset

Comment: >>>The server name, the DB name, **the username** and password are all correct (screenshot below)<<< By the way, your screenshot of SSMS shows quite another login, something strarting with Sparx, and the picture of your failed configuration shows EA_dbuse

Comment: @sepupic, accessing the error log helped me figure out what the problem is.

The "Server authentication", was set to "Windows Authentication mode". When I changed it to "SQL Server and Windows Authentication mode", I successfully established the connection. 

Thank you so much for your help! I really appreciate it.